# Applying [JsonIgnore] to property causes DataAnnotation attributes to be "lost"

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations, json.net

Given the following code:

```
    [JsonIgnore]
    [Display(Name = "Loan Cap")]
    public virtual string SomeProperty { get; protected set; }
```

When the DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider.CreateMetadata is called by ASP.NET MVC to fulfil the following call:

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SomeAttribute)
```

The list of attributes handed to CreateMetadata does not include the [Display] attribute (or the [JsonIgnore] for that matter).  If I remove the [JsonIgnore] then the [Display] gets found and passed to CreateMetadata.  Anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Why is your `SomeAttribute` virtual? Maybe you pass an object as your model which overrides `SomeAttribute` when you put `JsonIgnore` on it. Can you post some more context? Because `JsonIgnore` is a part of a third party library so `DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider.CreateMetadata` - which is a part of .net fw - cannot handle it specially so your problem will be somewhere else.

Comment: I'm sorry, in my haste to post, I called it SomeAttribute, I meant SomeProperty (and have edited it to reflect that).  I'm not looking to have CreateMetadata handle JsonIgnore, But putting JsonIgnore on the property causes all other attributes to be lost.

Comment: **Correction** Applying [JsonIgnore] causes all attributes to be lost (including the JsonIgnore)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug/issue in older versions of the Newtonsoft.Json nuget package.
I confirmed the issue exists in version 9.0.1 of the package

> **This issue is fixed in version 10.0.1**

In my case, I was getting Entity Framework migration pending changes errors when executing, but not from Package Manager Console.  I discovered that this is because of this same issue, the JsonIgnore attribute causing all attributes to be "lost"  The console commands, "Update-Database" and "Add-Migration" still saw a ForeignKey attribute. But if the code was executing, Entity Framework didn't see the ForeignKey attribute and threw a pending changes migration error.