# EF NotMapped & JsonIgnore attributes causing code-first issues

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have some model classes which are used as Entity Framework code-first models. I have some properties on these models which are not part of the database schema, and to ensure that Entity Framework doesn't get confused, I have marked these properties with the `[NotMapped]` attribute. When I generate code-first migrations for the models, these properties are correctly ignored.

However, I have recently added `[JsonIgnore]` attributes to these same properties, as the model classes are being de/serialized and these properties are not appropriate to include in the serialization. This also works fine - but it has had the very strange consequence of the EF code-first migrations not recognizing the `[NotMapped]` attributes. Now I am getting the error where entity framework thinks that the model classes are out of sync with the database - but when I generate a new migration, it thinks that it needs to add columns for all of the previously not-mapped properties. Removing the `[JsonIgnore]` attribute from these properties resolves the issue.

I see that this issue has been experienced before, outside the context of Entity Framework, in this question (with no answer): [Applying [JsonIgnore] to property causes DataAnnotation attributes to be "lost"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11941223/applying-jsonignore-to-property-causes-dataannotation-attributes-to-be-lost)

Is this a well-understood behavior of the C# attributing system? Or is it specific to the `[JsonIgnore]` attribute - and if so, what causes it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `[DataContract]` and `[DataMember]` attributes to define which properties you want serialized.

```
[DataContract]
public class EntityA
{
    [DataMember]
    public string SerializeThisProperty { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public string DoNotSerializeThisProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I will try this and see if it works. But can you explain why using JsonIgnore is causing this issue?

Comment: This did resolve my issue. Thank you. I am still curious as to why JsonIgnore caused it in the first place.